# Vue CLI with Browsersync: You may need an appropriate loader (#!)

Tags: webpack, browser-sync, vue-cli-3

I'm hitting a weird issue when starting from Vue-CLI-generated templates. Trying to simply import browser-sync triggers the following error.

File: ./node_modules/browser-sync/dist/index.js

```
Module parse failed: Unexpected character '#' (1:0)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.
> #! /usr/bin/env node
| "use strict";
| /**
```

**Steps to Reproduce**

- Using the Vue CLI (^3.3.0) and BrowserSync (^2.26.3)...

```
vue create new-project
cd new-project
```

- Install BrowserSync

```
npm install browser-sync
```

- Add to src/main.js

```
const bs = require('browser-sync').create();
```

**What hasn't worked:**

- Adding `shebang-loader` to Webpack
- Updating `vue-cli`
- Fresh template using `vue create new-project`

Comment: It seems the `index.js` contains shell code ( https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shebang_(Unix) )

Comment: @Adriano Yep. The weirdest part to me is that if I create a new Node project from scratch (without the Vue CLI), I have no problem using:
```const bs = require('browser-sync').create();```

I think this is not an issue with the `browser-sync` module, but a problem with how the Vue CLI configures Webpack?